# Pinax-referrals, how to remove the domain name from generated referral link and connect it to a view

Tags: python, django

I am working on pinax-referrals integrating it with my Django app. So far I have managed to generate referral code for every user that has signed up. My problem is that when I output those referral links generated for a user, it includes a domain name that is

```
http://example.com/referrals/iqtK4SBNWcE59TN2E2oCbRZcS4ui1sadtO8iHyB3/
```

How can I remove that domain name (example.com) and replace it with the domain name of my local host domain (127.0.0.1:8000).

Also from the above, I have created a view which welcomes a user who has joined using a referral link. I want the view to display the name of the referrer, something like, "welcome, you have been invited by {{ the  username of the referrer }} ".   But am having a challenge to connect that referral link to my welcome view for the referred users. i have tried to search the pinax-referral documentation but it is not bringing it out clearly for a newbee like me to understand well. any help so please

signals.py

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from .models import Profile
from pinax.referrals.models import Referral

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def save_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs['request'] 
    user = kwargs['user']
    print(user)


    referral = Referral.create(

        user = user,
        redirect_to = reverse("Home:afterlogin")

    )

    profile = Profile.objects.create(user= user, referral = referral)

    profile.save()
```

This works fine to allocate each user with  unique referral code

views.py

```
class welcomeafterLoginView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "refferal_page.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get the context
        context = super(welcomeafterLoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Create any data and add it to the context
        referral_code =Profile.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
        context['referral_code'] = referral_code
        return context
```

referral_page.html

```
{{referral_code.referral.url }}
```

this code outputs the following:
http://example.com/referrals/iqtK4SBNWcE59TN2E2oCbRZcS4ui1sadtO8iHyB3/

How do i get rid of this 'example.com'. and assign it the sites domain i.e localhost(127.0.0.1:8000)

Also the how do i connect the generated code to be tweeted , to a view whereby when  the tweeted refferal is clicked it returns the view, saying , "welcome, you have been invited by {{the username of the reffereer}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for using Pinax.

## On the Domain Name of the Referral URL.

Pinax-referrals constructs referral URLs from the current site of the containing Django project.

When you use the Django sites framework in your project, on running the first migration Django creates a default site named `example.com` with the domain `example.com` and saves this to your database.

So, when you set `SITE_ID = 1` in your settings file, you are declaring this `example.com` site as the current site in the project.

One way to make the current site of your project point to what you'd like is to create a site object with the right domain and name, and point the `SITE_ID` setting in your settings file to the id of this site object.

You confirm the current site for your project this way:

```py
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.get_current()
<Site: example.com>
```

To change this, you can create a custom site object, note down its id, and point the `SITE_ID` setting in your settings file to the id of this custom site object.

```py
>>> s = Site.objects.create(domain="not-example.com", name="not-example.com")
<Site: not-example.com>
>>> s.id
2 # could be something else
```

**Remember to point the `SITE_ID` setting in your settings file to the id of this site object.**

Runserver (if it was currently running) will reload the settings file, and the current site of your project will now point to the appropriate site.

Now, the urls of your referral objects will have the correct domain name.

## On Getting the Referrer in a View

The referrer is available on the `user` attribute of the referral object, so if you already have the referral object, you can construct that nice sentence you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the all-auth default site  that generates the example.com... In your admin panel, you can change the site from example.com to your domain name